# Permanently adding to %PATH% from Python

Tags: python, windows

For some reason I have to write Python for Windows (extremely tedious), and can't find a way to append the script's current directory to the PATH environment variable.

I know about

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + <current_directory>
```

but this doesn't do it for me since the change is not permanent.

All the answers point to changing the PATH by using the GUI (System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables). I want to automate my tool as much as possible so the user only has to run the `config.py` file and start working, without worrying too much about path variables.

On Linux I just wrote to .bashrc and sourced the file. How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: @ecatmur The answer for the question you linked gives vbscript solution. This question asks explicitly for a Python solution and therefore is not a duplicate.

Comment: Hey! I think that works for me, I was just looking for some pointers. I'll try modifying the registry using Python, see if I can work something out.

Comment: I can't post the answer since the question is on hold due to being marked as a duplicate (incorrectly). Still you can edit Windows registry with https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html module. Update `"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path"`. Remember to append your path to the existing value. Don't replace the whole thing.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thank you! I got it now.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo the question is language-agnostic, so it's irrelevant that the accepted answer is in VBScript.

Comment: Don't follow the recommendation to use setx.exe. That would make a mess. The user `Path` needs to be edited separate from the system path and retain the original unexpanded environment variables. You should preferably modify the user's value in `HKCU\Environment` rather than the system value, unless you really need to modify it for all users. Also, keep the original data type (`REG_SZ` vs `REG_EXPAND_SZ`), except if the value has more than one "%" in it you should use `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. And remember to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message to not require logging off and on.

Comment: @ecatmur How is `Permanently adding to %PATH% from Python` language agnostic?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo the linked question is language-agnostic, and an answer in VBScript can easily be translated into Python, so there's no need to have separate questions per language.